# Visual Studio 2013 cannot open custom project file

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I've created custom VSPackage which enable support of custom project type (.apcproj) according to this manual https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961.aspx

Now I have apcproj as template in New Project dialog. I have support of this extension in Open Project dialog.
But if I create or open this project type by using Visual Studio, IDE gives me error:

```
"Unsupported"
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.
```

How can I teach Visual Studio to open this project types?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the edition (Express, Ultimate, ...) Maybe with your edition this doesn't work? Just guessing.

Comment: I use Premium. I can create and install vsix but this vsix doesn't register apcproj extension support to visual studio

Comment: Similar issue ... I get the same error.

Comment: @user1829319  It was error in project factory. I can help you to solve problem if you share your source code to me